# How to use inlines after splitting the string based on special character in textblock in C# Wpf MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, string, split

I have a paragraph which contains ':' and '\n' .
I want to separate the string(a paragraph) first on '\n' and then based on ':' 
then need to bold the strings between \n and :

For example:
`**The definite **article** is the word** : It limits the meaning of a noun to one particular thing. For example, your friend might ask, “Are you going to the party this weekend?” \r\n
**The definite article** : It tells you that your friend is referring to a specific party that both of you know about.\r\n
**The definite article** :It can be used with singular, plural, or uncountable nouns.`

How can I just make a specific string in bold.the paragraph is dynamic.

Comment: What 'output-control' are you targeting to display your text? Because different fomatting inside of same control may not be trivial for all kinds of controls.

Comment: @AndreasH. Its is a textblock .a single textblock

Answer (score 1):

Luckily a `TextBlock` supports inline formatting. So I see two cases, my general approach would assume, that the text of every line between the start of the line and the first colon has to be bold, except there is no colon in that line.

It would look like this:

```
var lines = txt.Split('\n');

foreach(var line in lines)
{
    var parts = line.Split(':');
    for(int i = 0; i<parts.Length; i++)
    {
        txBlock1.Inlines.Add(
            new Run($"{parts[i]}{(i<parts.Length - 1 ? ":" : "\n")}")
                { FontWeight = (i==0 && parts.Length>1) ?  FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Regular});
    }
}
```

But, if you can surely expect the string to be formatted in such a way, that there is exactly one colon in every line, than you could shorten it a bit:

```
var erg = txt.Split(new char[] { '\n', ':'});
for(int i = 0; i<erg.Length;i++)
{
    var isEven = (i & 1) == 0;
    txBlock1.Inlines.Add(
        new Run($"{erg[i]}{(isEven ? ":" : "\n")}")
        { FontWeight = isEven ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Regular });
}
```